# Display text on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html

Hy there, this is what I have reached since now:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function unhide(divID) {
 var item = document.getElementById(divID);
 if (item) { 
 item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden'; }}
 </script>
<h3><strong><a href="javascript:unhide('Juli');"><span style="color:#000000;">Juli</span></a></strong></h3>
<div id="col2">
    <div id="Juli">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Von</th>
                    <th>Bis</th>
                    <th>Promoter</th>
                    <th>Strecke</th>
                    <th>Preis</th>
                    <th>Anmeldung</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>08.07.2013</td>
                    <td>08.07.2013</td>
                    <td><a href="index.php/en/events-promoters/rehm">REHM RACEDAYS</a></td>
                    <td>Imola</td>
                    <td>245,00 €</td>
                    <td><a href="">ausgebucht</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <strong><a href="javascript:unhide('August');"><span style="color:#000000;">August</span></a></strong></h3>
    <div id="col3">
        <div class="hidden" id="August">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                                            <th>Von</th>
                        <th>Bis</th>
                        <th>Promoter</th>
                        <th>Preis</th>
                        <th>Link</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here the URL: http://www.dieraber.altervista.org/index.php/en/rennstrecken-terminenn
I would like that on clicking the month the table is displayed just like it is now, and that on mouseover the month link it is displayed too. Can anyone help me? Thx

Comment: The site doesn't work on Firefox BTW

Comment: Sounds like you are searching for [the title attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes).

Comment: yes I know, the logo is displayed to big, but I cant find the reason

Answer (score 2):

You can attach the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` attributes to your hyperlinks.

```
<a href="javascript:unhide('Juli');" onmouseover="unhide('Juli');" onmouseout="unhide('Juli');"><span style="color:#000000;">Juli</span></a>
```

I notice you're using the same function to hide and unhide. You may want to create two separate functions, because with the code I've supplied, hovering the mouse over the link will unhide it, but clicking the link will then hide it again.

Comment: thanks, it works!!!!! Youre are right, but I put away onmouseout and it works grate too, on second onmouseover the div is hide. The unhide function with the links well be need for mobile browser.

Comment: just a last quetion: how could i make that there is unhide only one div at maximum? for example if you unhide july and mouseover on august july gets closed? thanks again

Comment: You could use `<a href="javascript:unhide('Juli'); unhide('August'); unhide('September'); unhide('Oktober');">Juli</a>`. Essentially, this would toggle the visibility of all of the tables. This could break easily, though, because it assumes that one of the tables is already open. For this reason I strongly suggest that you turn `hide()` and `unhide()` into separate functions.

Comment: allright, think I will made it as you recommend. But could I give the same item.className=='hidden' to both function?

Comment: Yes, you could. And to show it again, you could use `item.className=''` to remove the `hidden` class.

Comment: allright, i create this 2 funtions: `function unhide(divID) {
 var item = document.getElementById(divID);
 if (item) {
 item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden';
 }
 }
 function hide(divID) {
 var item = document.getElementById(divID);
 if (item) {
 item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'hidden';
 }
 }`

Comment: but what for class should i assign to the div? If I make to different item.classname== hide and unhidde fór the 2 function, i can make the div only hidden or unhidden.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do that without JavaScript with just CSS:

```
.item-page h3:hover + div .hidden { 
    display:block;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: I'd say that if you ever find a situation where CSS can do exactly what you're looking to do with Javascript, choose CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the `title` attribute:

```
<span title="this is the tooltip text">hove me</span>
```